# Exclude Area within a Graphics Path

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I am working with GDI and trying to draw an object from top view.  I want to draw a round footstool with feet but when you look from the top only see the feet outside of the main circle.

I see plenty of examples of clipping everything outside but I want to clip every thing inside the circle and then paint the circle outline.

Here is sample code to demo what I'm trying to do.  Probably very easy and I've tried including region.exclude but cant get anything to work.

```
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(500, 500)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent)
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Default

   ' Add 4 Feet
    Dim npoints As Point() = {New Point(50, 5), New Point(95, 50), New Point(50, 95), New Point(5, 50), _
                        New Point(5, 5), New Point(90, 90), New Point(0, 0), New Point(100, 100)}
    Dim gp As New GraphicsPath

    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.DarkGray, 1)
    Dim FeetSize As Size = New Size(10, 10)
    For I As Integer = 0 To 3
        gp.AddEllipse(New Rectangle(New Point(NPoints(I).X - (FeetSize.Width / 2), NPoints(I).Y - (FeetSize.Height / 2)), FeetSize))
    Next
    g.DrawPath(p, gp)

    ' I want to do clipping now; ie everything inside circle region below

    ' Then draw the main footstool circle
    gp.Reset()
    gp.AddEllipse(NPoints(4).X, NPoints(4).Y, NPoints(5).X, NPoints(5).Y)
    g.DrawPath(p, gp)

    ' Set Picturebox Value
    PictureBox1.Image = bmp
```

[Update] I found a solution using graphics.excludeclip:

```
       ' Add Feet
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.DarkGray, 1)
    Dim FeetSize As Size = New Size(10, 10)
    For I As Integer = 0 To 3
        gp.AddEllipse(New Rectangle(New Point(NPoints(I).X - (FeetSize.Width / 2), NPoints(I).Y - (FeetSize.Height / 2)), FeetSize))
    Next
    ' Clip Exclude Circle
    Dim egp As New GraphicsPath
    egp.AddEllipse(NPoints(4).X, NPoints(4).Y, NPoints(5).X, NPoints(5).Y)
    g.ExcludeClip(New Region(egp))

    ' Draw Result
    g.DrawPath(p, gp)

    ' Draw Circle
    g.ResetClip()
    gp.Reset()
    gp.AddEllipse(NPoints(4).X, NPoints(4).Y, NPoints(5).X, NPoints(5).Y)
    g.FillPath(New SolidBrush(FillColour), gp)
    g.DrawPath(p, gp)
```

Comment: When I draw this I can see the feet circles cut through by the top circle - so I can see 5 complete circles - is that not right?

Comment: Can you update your post with a pic of what you get and a pic of what you want?

Comment: Actually Stackoverflow doesn't let me post the picture because my rating is too low at the moment.  Seems to be catch-22.

Comment: Be sure to dispose the `GraphicsPaths` and the `Pen` - Using blocks work great.